# displaying page orientation option using UIprintInteractionController

Tags: ios

How can I show page orientation option using `UIPrintInteractionController`? Actually I want to use a switch to let the user choose which orientation he wants to print. Any help would be great. I have tried using the delegate methods for `UIPrintInteractionController`.

```
    - (UIViewController *)printInteractionControllerParentViewController:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController
      {

        return nav;

      }

    - (void)printInteractionControllerWillPresentPrinterOptions:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController
      {
        UISwitch * orietationSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 200,50, 21)];


        [nav.topViewController.view  addSubview:orietationSwitch];

       }
```

Comment: Any One ?? I have tried to do anything which I found on the stack as well as on the web. Any workaround or better solution.